# Modelling the effect of a structure on a "tsunami" (hyperbolic wave equation)

Tags: differential-equations, modeling

So, the hyperbolic wave equation can be quite easily solved in *Mathematica* like this:

```
L = 5; 
TMax = 10; 
tsunamiEqn = 
  u /. NDSolve[{
      D[u[t, x, y], t, t] == D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y], 
      u[0, x, y] == 0.15/E^(x^2 + y^2), 
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0, 
      u[t, -L, y] == u[t, L, y], 
      u[t, x, -L] == u[t, x, L]}, 
      u, {t, 0, TMax}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}][[1]];
```

One can then plot it or `Manipulate` it via the following snippet:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
  tsunamiEqn[fac TMax, x, y], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L},
  PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, {-L, L}, {-0.1, 0.2}},
  Mesh -> 10,
  PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Specularity[White, 50]}
  ],
 {fac, 0, 0.9}
 ]
```

**Now my question is**:

How do I include a structure inside this "pond". I would like to see what happens when the wave interacts with a square block or so.

I am drawing a blank right now as to how I would want to include that: A boundary condition? (would seem a little complex)

**Here are a few snapshots of this wave travelling:**
[image: Time=0]

[image: Time=0.2 TMax]

[image: Time=0.3 TMax]

Comment: The code from the question may help you a little bit: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30658/5478

Comment: @Kuba Very interesting answer that was!

Comment: Effect of tsunami on a structure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the scalar approximation, the obstacle could be modeled by an abrupt change in the wave speed $c$. This speed is unity in your original calculation, and I'm just going to insert its inverse square as a prefactor in front of the second time derivative.

The spatial shape is defined as an elongated box using [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Boole.html):

```
tsunamiEqn = 
  u /. NDSolve[{(1/(1 - 0.98*Boole[Abs[x - 3.5] < 1 && Abs[y] < 2]))*
        D[u[t, x, y], t, t] == 
       D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y], 
      u[0, x, y] == 0.15 Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], 
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0, u[t, -L, y] == u[t, L, y],
       u[t, x, -L] == u[t, x, L]}, 
     u, {t, 0, TMax}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}][[1]];
```

Now there is a warning because I enlarged the spatial domain without changing the precision or method options, just so I can see the reflection before the waves hit the boundary:

```
l = Table[
   Plot3D[tsunamiEqn[fac TMax, x, y], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, {-L, L}, {-0.1, 0.2}}, Mesh -> 10, 
    PlotPoints -> 50, 
    PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Specularity[White, 50]}], {fac, 0, 
    0.9, .09}];

ListAnimate[l]
```

[image: wave]

It's important to **increase the number of plot points** in the visualization, because the default is too coarse to show the details of the wave properly.

You may also want to manually select a different method, e.g. as I did [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27996/245), to avoid the warning message in `NDSolve`.

Comment: Very interesting! I'll see how this cranks out on my computer.