# How to exchange interpolating function results of NDSolve between different platforms?

Tags: export, interpolation

For example, I have a interpolating function solution by NDSolve in a windows x64 platform and want to share the result to users in other windows x86.

I tried the DumpSave and ".mx" binary format, but failed since ".mx" is not platform independent binary format.

However, ".wdx", developed by Wolfram in 2007, which is said to be independent on platforms, does not work either. I just obtain the similar error message when trying to `Get` or `Import`, on x86 platform, the ".mx" or ".wdx" binary files created by Win64 platform with a failure:

> File interpolatingFunctionData.wdx was written with ABI 64, which is not compatible with this version of the Wolfram Language.

It seems ".mat" does not support interpolating function `Export`ing.

Then how should I exchange interpolating function data between different platforms?

Comment: How about Export[file.txt, Compress[interpolationObject]]

Comment: thank you very much! I think this should work. Can you please `answer` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Export["file.txt", Compress[Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}]]];
Uncompress[Import["file.txt"]]
```

Comment: Though this should work, it doesn't really work. I don't know why.

Comment: Though this does not work. e.g., I tried to exchange the solution of the PDE in the tsunami model here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107988/how-to-solve-the-tsunami-model-and-animate-the-shallow-water-wave?lq=1 , after transering the result from an x64 to an x86 windows machine, the same code visualizations look different (interpolating function basically changed in values). All other things are OK. Since there seems no other better solution, this answer is still acceptable.