# InitializeBoundaryConditions::fembdnl: The dependent variable in the boundary condition needs to be linear

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method

Checking the documentation on the error were of not that much help to me. Can someone please suggest how to deal with it?

```
rhop = 10922; rhon = 10922; Cp = 200; Cn = 200; Lan = 1.5*10^(-3); Lap = 1.5*10^(-3); Lbn = 1.5*10^(-3);
Lbp = 1.5*10^(-3); kp = 1.8; kn = 2.2; sigmap = 1/(1.2*10^(-5)); sigman = 1/(10^(-5)); taup = 0.00027; 
taun = -0.000156; L = 2.325*10^(-3); ha = 10;

Tinf = 298; Th = 300; Tc = 298; A = 2.325*10^(-6); Ic = 0.5;

PDE1 = rhop*Cp*D[Tp[x, y, z, t], t] == kp*(D[D[Tp[x, y, z, t], x], x] + D[D[Tp[x, y, z, t], y], y] + 
       D[D[Tp[x, y, z, t], z], z]) + 1/sigmap*(Ic/A)^2 - 
    taup*Ic/A*D[Tp[x, y, z, t], x];

PDE2 = rhon*Cn*D[Tn[x, y, z, t], t] == kn*(D[D[Tn[x, y, z, t], x], x] + D[D[Tn[x, y, z, t], y], y] + 
       D[D[Tn[x, y, z, t], z], z]) + 1/sigman*(Ic/A)^2 + 
    taun*Ic/A*D[Tn[x, y, z, t], x];

Bc1 = kp*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Tp][x, 0, z, t] == ha*(Tp[x, 0, z, t] - Tinf);

Bc2 = kn*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Tn][x, 0, z, t] == ha*(Tn[x, 0, z, t] - Tinf);

Bc3 = -kp*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Tp][x, Lap, z, t] == ha*(Tp[x, Lap, z, t] - Tinf);

Bc4 = -kn*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Tn][x, Lan, z, t] == ha*(Tn[x, Lan, z, t] - Tinf);

Bc5 = kp*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][Tp][x, y, 0, t] == ha*(Tp[x, y, 0, t] - Tinf);

Bc6 = kn*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][Tn][x, y, 0, t] == ha*(Tn[x, y, 0, t] - Tinf);

Bc7 = -kp*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][Tp][x, y, Lbp, t] == ha*(Tp[x, y, Lbp, t] - Tinf);

Bc8 = -kn*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][Tn][x, y, Lbn, t] == ha*(Tn[x, y, Lbn, t] - Tinf);

Bc9 = DirichletCondition[Tp[x, y, z, t] == Tc, x == 0];

Bc10 = DirichletCondition[Tn[x, y, z, t] == Tc, x == 0];

Bc11 = DirichletCondition[Tp[x, y, z, t] == Th, x == L];

Bc12 = DirichletCondition[Tn[x, y, z, t] == Th, x == L];

sol = NDSolve[{PDE1, PDE2, Tp[x, y, z, 0] == 0, Tn[x, y, z, 0] == 0, 
   Bc1, Bc2, Bc3, Bc4, Bc5, Bc6, Bc7, Bc8, Bc9, Bc10, Bc11, 
   Bc12}, {Tp, Tn}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, Lap}, {z, 0, Lbp}]
```

Comment: To be more specific: your `DirichletCondition` has forced `NDSolve` to turn to `FiniteElement` method, but `FiniteElement` cannot handle b.c. involving derivative. Since your problem can be handled by the old good `TensorProductGrid`, simplest solution is to avoid `DirichletCondition` in your code.

Comment: @xzczd I have tried avoiding DirichletCondition but its taking very long to evaluate without producing any output.

Comment: Try adjusting the sub-options of `TensorProductGrid`. Lower `DifferenceOrder` and `MaxPoints` should help. (Don't forget currently `FiniteElement` is just order 2. )

Comment: @xzczd I tried `Method -> {"MethodOfLines",    "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100},    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 200,      "MinPoints" -> 200, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}` but no luck.

Comment: Since it's a 3+1D problem, I won't be surprised if `200` is too demanding. Consider starting from `20`. Also, you can use the tools here to monitor the solving process: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134787/1871

Comment: @xzczd In this article the authors have used FDM to solve these PDEs. 10.1016/j.ijheatmasstransfer.2009.12.056

Comment: Why don't you use NeumannValue for your PBCs - that what it's for. You don't need all those factors in front of the Derivative. Have a look at the [Heat Transfer tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html)

Comment: @user21 It worked but the results are not correct.

Comment: @zhk and they are correct with the TPG method? Perhaps a sing issue?

Comment: @user21 yes! Correct with TPG

Comment: @user21 Whats the correct way to define for example Bc1 interms of `NeumannValue`?