# Strange behavior of NDSolve (Error NDSolve::ntdvdae)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

i discovered a weird behavior using ```NDSolve``` to solve a set of differential equations.

*Let me outline my problem*:
I need to solve a set of differential equations. These are equations of motion where the number of equations is depending on the number of shape functions i use.
If i use 8 shape functions i'll get a set of 8 differential equations which `NDSolve` is evaluating. So there are 8 generalized coordinates (from `Subscript[qq, 1][t]` to `Subscript[qq, 8][t]`) which need to be solved via `NDSolve`.
If i switch the number of shape functions to 9 which means i'll get 9 equations to solve, the `NDSolve` function is reporting the error message `NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations.`
(**Please find the list of 8 and the list of 9 equations below to copy paste it into Mathematica. Furthermore i added the syntax i used for solving these equations. See also the initial conditions below in the code.**)
(I use Version **12.1.1.0**)

Since i need to solve it for 9 (or more) shape functions/equations i wanted to ask you guys if anybody can please help me fixing my problem? I looked it up on the internet but have no idea on how to fix it and i really appreciate any hint of you guys ;-)

---

Here's the list with 8 equations to solve

```
ListDGL8={-129.006137732798*Sin[334.7356174047985*t] + 
16038.147354412993*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
8019.073677207725*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
6961.710838517229*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      6433.029419170023*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
6085.362833097541*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
5828.203660787876*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
5627.085115515234*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      5464.773786742095*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
0.12299999999999997*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
0.06149999999999988*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
      0.035142857142857226*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.021964285714285738*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
0.014642857142857091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
      0.010250000000000066*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.0074545454545454*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
0.005590909090909075*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] == 0, 
  -64.50306886639892*Sin[334.7356174047985*t] + 
8019.073677206336*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
12830.008260286922*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
12301.32684094079*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      11550.385255502828*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
10889.951086133398*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
10344.260387403454*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
9896.079764234863*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      9525.500273098965*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
0.0615*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
0.03514285714285714*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
      0.021964285714285714*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.014642857142857124*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
0.010250000000000037*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
      0.007454545454545436*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.005590909090909091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
0.004300699300699318*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] == 0, 
  -36.656551732634455*Sin[334.7356174047985*t] + 
6961.710838516545*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
12301.326840942595*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
14022.914961281625*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      14397.108145685284*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
14318.736070694373*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
14083.571128609241*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
13802.756401830295*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      13520.571185562003*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
0.03514285714285714*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
0.021964285714285714*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
      0.014642857142857124*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.010250000000000037*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
0.007454545454545436*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
      0.005590909090909091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.004300699300699318*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
0.003379120879120845*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] == 0, 
  -22.733293165752244*Sin[334.7356174047985*t] + 
6433.029419171642*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
11550.385255508896*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
14397.108145690378*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      15694.295645717299*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
16267.381548618549*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
16480.82839766756*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
16509.967514004966*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      16444.178366731503*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
0.021964285714285714*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
0.014642857142857124*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
      0.010250000000000037*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.007454545454545436*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
0.005590909090909091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
      0.004300699300699318*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.003379120879120845*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
0.0027032967032967203*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] == 0, 
  -15.02696945487861*Sin[334.7356174047985*t] + 
6085.362831948756*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
10889.951086136134*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
14318.736070694926*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      16267.381548612495*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
17397.880350381078*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
18054.639540893724*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
18428.607549193897*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      18629.97845286259*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
0.014642857142857124*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
0.010250000000000037*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
      0.007454545454545436*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.005590909090909091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
0.004300699300699318*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
      0.003379120879120845*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.0027032967032967203*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
0.0021964285714285714*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] == 0, 
  -10.429113172009295*Sin[334.7356174047985*t] + 
5828.203660786874*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
10344.26038740584*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
14083.571128609183*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      16480.82839766034*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
18054.639540892793*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
19102.808844437823*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
19807.616279822425*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      20283.79973727325*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
0.010250000000000037*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
0.007454545454545436*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
      0.005590909090909091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.004300699300699318*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
0.003379120879120845*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
      0.0027032967032967203*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.0021964285714285714*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
0.0018088235294117516*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] == 0, 
  -7.5222261315258265*Sin[334.7356174047985*t] + 
5627.085115509573*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
9896.079764229798*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
13802.756401820458*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      16509.96751398605*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
18428.60754918051*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
19807.616279809037*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
20810.86977714626*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      21548.654009568505*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
0.007454545454545436*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
0.005590909090909091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
      0.004300699300699318*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.003379120879120845*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
0.0027032967032967203*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
      0.0021964285714285714*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.0018088235294117516*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
0.0015073529411764874*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] == 0, 
  -5.597559240622573*Sin[334.7356174047985*t] + 
5464.773801028572*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
9525.500273096026*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
13520.571185554669*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      16444.178366715205*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
18629.97845285246*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
20283.799737262772*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
21548.65400957316*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      22526.08801129856*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
0.005590909090909091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
0.004300699300699318*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
      0.003379120879120845*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.0027032967032967203*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
0.0021964285714285714*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
      0.0018088235294117516*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.0015073529411764874*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
0.0012693498452012453*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] == 0};
```

---

Here's the list with 9 equations to solve

```
ListDGL9={-129.006137732798*Sin[334.73556652336856*t] + 
16038.147354411205*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
8019.073677208609*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
6961.710838517458*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      6433.029418026366*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
6085.362832099767*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
5828.2036607934715*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
5627.085123744895*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      5464.773809254926*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
5331.03754389986*Subscript[qq, 9][t] + 
0.12299999999999997*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
      0.06149999999999988*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
0.035142857142857226*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.021964285714285738*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
      0.014642857142857091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
0.010250000000000066*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.0074545454545454*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
      0.005590909090909075*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] + 
0.00430069930069936*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 9]][t] == 0, 
  -64.50306886639892*Sin[334.73556652336856*t] + 
8019.0736772033815*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
12830.008260288385*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
12301.326840941168*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      11550.385255510206*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
10889.95108613008*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
10344.26038741265*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
9896.079764221562*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      9525.500273072714*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
9216.11355334177*Subscript[qq, 9][t] + 
0.06149999999999988*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
      0.035142857142857226*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
0.021964285714285738*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.014642857142857091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
      0.010250000000000066*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
0.0074545454545454*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.005590909090909075*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
      0.00430069930069936*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] + 
0.003379120879120816*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 9]][t] == 0, 
  -36.656551732634455*Sin[334.73556652336856*t] + 
6961.710838512762*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
12301.326840944486*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
14022.914961282135*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      14397.108145694714*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
14318.736070690153*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
14083.571128621115*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
13802.75640181324*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      13520.5711855283*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
13254.50707224186*Subscript[qq, 9][t] + 
0.035142857142857226*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
      0.021964285714285738*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
0.014642857142857091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.010250000000000066*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
      0.0074545454545454*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
0.005590909090909075*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.00430069930069936*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
      0.003379120879120816*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] + 
0.002703296703296745*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 9]][t] == 0, 
  -22.733293165752244*Sin[334.73556652336856*t] + 
6433.029419167233*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
11550.385255511093*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
14397.10814569096*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      15694.29564572827*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
16267.381548613543*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
16480.828397681238*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
16509.967513985117*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      16444.178366692387*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
16330.908579364535*Subscript[qq, 9][t] + 
0.021964285714285738*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
      0.014642857142857091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
0.010250000000000066*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.0074545454545454*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
      0.005590909090909075*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
0.00430069930069936*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.003379120879120816*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
      0.002703296703296745*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] + 
0.0021964285714285636*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 9]][t] == 0, 
  -15.02696945487861*Sin[334.73556652336856*t] + 
6085.3628319438685*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
10889.951086138535*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
14318.736070695479*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      16267.381548624719*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
17397.880350375548*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
18054.639540908975*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
18428.60754917178*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      18629.9784528194*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
18724.397981297923*Subscript[qq, 9][t] + 
0.014642857142857091*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
      0.010250000000000066*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
0.0074545454545454*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.005590909090909075*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
      0.00430069930069936*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
0.003379120879120816*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.002703296703296745*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
      0.0021964285714285636*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] + 
0.0018088235294117583*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 9]][t] == 0, 
  -10.429113172009295*Sin[334.73556652336856*t] + 
5828.20366078161*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
10344.260387408489*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
14083.571128609881*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      16480.82839767344*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
18054.63954088709*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
19102.808844453888*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
19807.616279798793*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      20283.79973722587*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
20605.19607634237*Subscript[qq, 9][t] + 
0.010250000000000066*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
      0.0074545454545454*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
0.005590909090909075*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.00430069930069936*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
      0.003379120879120816*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
0.002703296703296745*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.0021964285714285636*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
      0.0018088235294117583*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] + 
0.001507352941176465*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 9]][t] == 0, 
  -7.5222261315258265*Sin[334.73556652336856*t] + 
5627.085115504011*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
9896.079764232622*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
13802.756401821214*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      16509.96751399996*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
18428.607549174223*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
19807.61627982615*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
20810.869777121115*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      21548.65400951868*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
22096.273533439962*Subscript[qq, 9][t] + 
0.0074545454545454*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
      0.005590909090909075*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
0.00430069930069936*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.003379120879120816*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
      0.002703296703296745*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
0.0021964285714285636*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.0018088235294117583*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
      0.001507352941176465*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] + 
0.0012693498452012474*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 9]][t] == 0, 
  -5.597559240622573*Sin[334.73556652336856*t] + 
5464.773801022766*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
9525.500273098907*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
13520.571185555425*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      16444.178366729408*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
18629.978452845942*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
20283.79973728105*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
21548.65400954662*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      22526.08801124734*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
23288.863232276402*Subscript[qq, 9][t] + 
0.005590909090909075*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
      0.00430069930069936*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
0.003379120879120816*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.002703296703296745*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
      0.0021964285714285636*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
0.0018088235294117583*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.001507352941176465*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
      0.0012693498452012474*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] + 
0.001078947368421073*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 9]][t] == 0, 
  -4.2742528997234785*Sin[334.73556652336856*t] + 
5331.037487920821*Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 
9216.113553331204*Subscript[qq, 2][t] + 
13254.507072221313*Subscript[qq, 3][t] + 
      16330.908579346724*Subscript[qq, 4][t] + 
18724.397981263348*Subscript[qq, 5][t] + 
20605.19607633236*Subscript[qq, 6][t] + 
22096.273533398286*Subscript[qq, 7][t] + 
      23288.863232202362*Subscript[qq, 8][t] + 
24251.03528175503*Subscript[qq, 9][t] + 
0.00430069930069936*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 1]][t] + 
      0.003379120879120816*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 2]][t] + 
0.002703296703296745*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 3]][t] + 
0.0021964285714285636*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 4]][t] + 
      0.0018088235294117583*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 5]][t] + 
0.001507352941176465*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 6]][t] + 
0.0012693498452012474*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 7]][t] + 
      0.001078947368421073*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 8]][t] + 
0.0009248120300751469*Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, 9]][t] == 0};
```

---

This works perfectly

```
NDSolve[{ListDGL8, Table[Subscript[qq, i][0] == 0, {i, 1, 8, 1}],Table[Subscript[qq, i]'[0] == 0, {i, 1, 8, 1}]},Table[Subscript[qq, i][t], {i, 1, 8, 1}], {t, 0, 0.2}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]
```

But this doesn't work

```
NDSolve[{ListDGL9, Table[Subscript[qq, i][0] == 0, {i, 1, 9, 1}],Table[Subscript[qq, i]'[0] == 0, {i, 1, 9, 1}]}, Table[Subscript[qq, i][t], {i, 1, 9, 1}], {t, 0, 0.2}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does `NDSolve` fail after spitting out the warning? If it doesn't, probably it's no more than a warning. At least in _v12.3_, `NDSolve` begins solving after the warning, it's just slow. You can use the tool [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134787/1871) to monitor `t`. To understand why the warning pops up, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136114/1871).

Comment: Solves the stated problem: `NDSolve[Join[
  Solve[ode9, Variables[ode9 /. Equal -> Subtract][[-9 ;;]]] /. 
   Rule -> Equal,
  Thread[
   Variables[ode9 /. Equal -> Subtract][[-18 ;; -10]] == 1 /. 
    t -> 0],
  Thread[
   D[Variables[ode9 /. Equal -> Subtract][[-18 ;; -10]], t] == 0 /. 
    t -> 0]
  ],
 Variables[ode9 /. Equal -> Subtract][[-18 ;; -10]], {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: If you're not familiar with what differential-algebraic systems are, and how they differ from conventional differential systems, here are some descriptions of them and how Mathematica solves them [for `DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveDifferentialAlgebraicEquations.html) and [for `NDSolve`.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html)

Comment: @xzczd I mean there is this warning and there is no result, even if i add the tool you suggested or add the "Method" you sent me a link. I don't get it. In the case of 9 shape functions there is just one additional equation as well as an additional term in every previous equation. I am not able to solve this system of ODE's for more than 8 shape functions. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: @Michael E2 i tried your suggestion but the result seems to be totally different from the result of *ode8*. Also there is a warning `General::stop` showing up.

Comment: @Michael Seifert I just wanted to use `NDSolve` to solve this set of ODE's (wich worked for 8 equations but doesn't for 9). So i wanted to ask you guys what the problem could be that Mathematica doesn't evaluate my list of 9 coupled ordinary differential equations?

Comment: @WM_noob5:  Most likely, the list of 9 equations you've provided does not uniquely determine all of the highest-order derivatives.  Mathematica will try to put the system into first-order form by solving the equations for $q''_1, q''_2$, etc.  But if your equations happen to be linearly dependent on each other (in terms of these highest derivatives), then at least one of these second derivatives will not be uniquely determined, and there will be a constraint on some of the lower derivatives of the system.  This would trigger the "DAE" warning  that you got.

Comment: One thing I forgot to ask explicitly: are you sure the system is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ListDGL9` system can be integrated by solving for the second derivatives with `Reduce` and then applying `NDSolve`.

```
List @@ Reduce[ListDGL9, Table[Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, n]][t], {n, 9}]]
NDSolveValue[{%, Table[Subscript[qq, i][0] == 0, {i, 9}], 
    Table[Subscript[qq, i]'[0] == 0, {i, 9}]}, 
    Table[Subscript[qq, i][t], {i, 9}], {t, 0, 0.2}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
Plot[%, {t, 0, 0.2}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, qq}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]

(* {Subscript[qq, 1]''[t] == 0. + 851.38 Sin[334.736 t] - 
    2.13301*10^8 Subscript[qq, 1][t] + 2.88179*10^7 Subscript[qq, 2][t] - 
    1.52512*10^8 Subscript[qq, 3][t] - 1.99633*10^8 Subscript[qq, 4][t] - 
    2.40066*10^8 Subscript[qq, 5][t] - 2.78433*10^8 Subscript[qq, 6][t] - 
    3.15154*10^8 Subscript[qq, 7][t] - 3.50561*10^8 Subscript[qq, 8][t] - 
    3.8486*10^8 Subscript[qq, 9][t], ... } *)
```

(expressions for the other `Subscript[qq, n_]''[t]` are qualitatively similar.)

[image]

This computation takes only several seconds.  The plot is qualitatively similar to that obtained for `ListDGL8`, although as noted in the question, `NDSolve` can be used directly to obtain the solution quickly.

**Addendum: Alternative Approaches**

Replacing

```
List @@ Reduce[ListDGL9, Table[Derivative[2][Subscript[qq, n]][t], {n, 9}]]
```

by

```
Rationalize[ListDGL9, 0]
```

in my solution above also produces the solution quickly.  There are several ways to produce the solution very slowly.  For instance, the last line of code in the question works on my computer, although the computation takes nearly 30 minutes.