# Wave scattering visualisation

Tags: visualization

I've been looking around on the web for some mathematica visualisation of a wave scattering with an interface or layer. I can't seem to find any nice 2-d or 3-d examples. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Something like [tsunami]( https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107988/how-to-solve-the-tsunami-model-and-animate-the-shallow-water-wave) ?

Comment: Thanks, it's a start!